# Historical Flight Landing Time

Tags: air-travel, airlines, timetables

I’m trying to track when Garuda Indonesia flight GIA 714 from DPS (Bali / Denpasar, Indonesia) landed at SYD (Sydney, Australia). The flight departed on 26th August 2019 at around 23:40, but I am unsure of the officially recorded landing time.

I can only go back 3 months on flight trackers like [FlightAware](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/GIA714) as a basic user.

Can someone look up the information for me?

Answer (score 4):

[image: Flight map]

Excerpts from CSV for the flight from Flightradar24:

```
Timestamp,UTC,Callsign,Position,Altitude,Speed,Direction
1566834918,2019-08-26T15:55:18Z,GIA714,"-8.748848,115.15612",0,43,87
1566834930,2019-08-26T15:55:30Z,GIA714,"-8.748655,115.161316",0,105,87
1566834936,2019-08-26T15:55:36Z,GIA714,"-8.748528,115.164474",0,125,87
1566834944,2019-08-26T15:55:44Z,GIA714,"-8.748333,115.169228",0,150,87
1566834950,2019-08-26T15:55:50Z,GIA714,"-8.748173,115.173622",0,165,87
1566834958,2019-08-26T15:55:58Z,GIA714,"-8.748001,115.180527",350,161,88
1566834966,2019-08-26T15:56:06Z,GIA714,"-8.74791,115.184456",650,156,88
1566834972,2019-08-26T15:56:12Z,GIA714,"-8.747864,115.189278",950,153,89
1566834979,2019-08-26T15:56:19Z,GIA714,"-8.747864,115.193687",1150,153,90
[...]
1566853105,2019-08-26T20:58:25Z,GIA714,"-33.909302,151.166382",175,125,168
1566853115,2019-08-26T20:58:35Z,GIA714,"-33.914886,151.167816",75,126,167
1566853125,2019-08-26T20:58:45Z,GIA714,"-33.921204,151.169403",0,126,168
1566853155,2019-08-26T20:59:15Z,GIA714,"-33.937031,151.173569",0,125,168
1566853178,2019-08-26T20:59:38Z,GIA714,"-33.946484,151.176041",0,59,168
```

As you can see, it took off at approx. 15:55UTC and it landed around 20:58UTC.

In addition to the map, you can see the [KML file for the flight](https://oc.bitsex.no/index.php/s/b1AEYJgBbLocty7) which can be imported into Google Earth or similar tools.

Comment: This info is far and beyond what I expected to receive. Very grateful! The Google earth import file is phenomenal and helps massively. Thanks again.